# Composer rejects package because of stability

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I created a package and here is it's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "faustuzas/theme-downloader",
    "description": "Easy to use bootstrap theme downloader",
    "type": "command",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Faustas Butkus",
            "email": "faustas.butkus@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

but when I try to require it via composer:
`composer require faustuzas/theme-downloader`

I get this error: 
[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `"minimum-stability": "stable"` because it's set to 'stable' by default. You have one branch and no tags so packagist show your package as dev-master which isn't stable. Try to create new branch e.g. `1.x` and add tag e.g. `1.0.0` then composer require again.